# Partition of a set, definition

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the [Book of Abstract Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486474178), a partition of a set is defined as:

> A partition of a set $A$ is a family $\{A_i : i \in I \}$ of nonempty
>   subsets of $A$ which are mutually disjoint and whose union is all of
>   $A$.

What is the set $I$ in this definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set $I$ is simply an *index set*: a set of labels used as subscripts to distinguish the members of the family. If the family is countably infinite, for instance, we might take $I$ to be $\Bbb N$, the set of natural numbers, and write the family as $\{A_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. However, any set can be used as an index set. Suppose, for instance, that for each real number $x$ I want to look at the set of rational numbers less than or equal to $x$. Then for each $x\in\Bbb R$ I might define $Q_x=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q\le x\}$ and talk about the indexed family $\{Q_x:x\in\Bbb R\}$; here $\Bbb R$, the set of real numbers, is my index set.

If you want to be formal about it, an indexed family $\mathscr{A}=\{A_i:i\in I\}$ is simply a function whose domain is a set $I$ of labels, or indices, and whose range is the family $\mathscr{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's what is often called an [indexing set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set).

Answer (score 1):

$I$ could be any set since the collection of subsets $A_i$ of $A$ indexed on $I$ has the desired property.